# Deny Access to Music Files URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, audio-player

I have a folder called music in the root of my website, and there is some music in it.

I got a script to create a music player and I'm getting the music from that folder:

```
<li><a href="music/jp.mp3">John Park</a></li>
<li><a href="music/oor.mp3">OOR</a></li>
```

And it is working pretty well but the problem is that people can access the music by entering the url, example:

```
http://localhost/musicplayer/music/jp.mp3
```

And if you access it from the url there is an option to download it.

So I made some research and I created a .htaccess file in the folder "music" and I have putted the code DENY FROM ALL.

And it worked people couldn't access to the mp3 url's, but now the script of music player can't run the music aswell.

So is there any fix for this problem, I would love it!

Summary: Forbid people to access url of the music but the script still get the musics.

Comment: The browser obviously _has to_ be able to request the URL, otherwise it would have no audio data to play to begin with. There is no trivial solution to this “problem”. If you need to fix it, then you should look into a streaming server solution, those usually implement measures to make it _harder_ for people to get to the data directly.

Comment: Theres no way to hide the download button when access directly to music url?

Comment: No, there is not. There are a few ways to make it _harder_ for technically less experienced users ... but those won’t even stop your average school kid.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to hide the mp3 files inside of a php script and use an apache rewrite rule to hide this.

```
RewriteRule ^musicplayer/music/jp\.php$ /musicplayer/music/jp.mp3 [L]
```

The above rule will make the end user think that they are viewing the mp3 file, but its actually a php script. Inside this script, you can then put some logic to determine whether you want to let the user view the file or not.

```
if(validrequest)
{
//output mp3
}
else
{
//invalid permissions
}
```

Comment: Ill test it when i arrive home, thanks! But it kinda seems a little complicated! Im not really used to code htaccess file.

Comment: It is a bit complicated, but you also dont need to hide the fact that its a php file. Instead, you can just reference the .php file in the href and this will still work, but it will be obvious to others that it is a php file, which i dont think is a bad thing. Either way, if you want to block people from accessing it via a url, you need to wrap the mp3 inside some php script to control the logic